# Como filtrar o formato do arquivo pelo input type file?

Tags: javascript, html

Quando ele é enviado eu faço uma validação  verificando se o arquivo escolhido é do formato que preciso assim:

```
function validaExtensao(id) {
   var result = true;
   var extensoes = new Array('xls'); // Arquivos permitidos
   var ext = $('#' + id).val().split(".")[1].toLowerCase();
   if ($.inArray(ext, extensoes) === -1) { // Arquivo não permitido
      result = false; 
   }
   return result;
}
```

Agora eu gostaria de filtrar quando e aberto o input file para mostrar apenas os tipos de arquivos correspondentes.

**Exemplo:**

Normal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tipo especificado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possivel fazer ? Cross-browser?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Utilize o atributo [`accept`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp).

Exemplo aceitando apenas arquivos `.xls`:

```html
<input type="file" name="meuInput" accept=".xls" />
```

Os valores do atributo podem ser:

- Extensão de arquivo (.xls, .jpg);
- `audio/*` - todos arquivos de áudio;
- `video/*` - todos arquivos de vídeo;
- `image/*` - todos arquivos de imagem;
- `media_type` - arquivos de mídia. <sub>[Lista de mídias](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)</sub>

Podem ser usados mais de um atributo, separados por vírgula, por exemplo:

```
<input accept="audio/*,video/*,image/*" />
```

**Nota:** segundo o [canIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=accept) nem todos os navegadores suportam, por exemplo IE9 e anteriores, Edge, iOS Safari.

Comment: `+1`, era isto mesmo, só um detalhe adicione o suporte dela nos navegadores, em alguns como IE9,iOS 9.2 e Opera não funcionam: http://caniuse.com/#search=accept

Comment: Perfeito, adicionado a nota, valeu pelo toque, ;)